# Making JButtons appear in front of a JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jlabel

I am making a simple 2D game using JAVA. Well, everything is doing well except for one thing, I cant make JButton appear in front of the JLabel. The JLabel that I am using serves as a background image. Picture this, when the program was executed, the JFrame has only one button in the middle, which has "play" as its text. When it is clicked, it vanishes and immediately, a background appears. if you roll over the mouse at the middle, the buttons which serves as the menu choices one by one appears. this is my question, How do I make the buttons(choices) apppear over  the image after the play button is clicked.? Thank you in advance..

Comment: 1) [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried) 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Card Layout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). You start the game by displaying the `button card`. Then when you click a button you display the `image card`.